# C++ encrypt/decrypt with the same key

Tags: c++, security, encryption

I am new to the security stuff. Is there any way to encrypt and decrypt a security key with the same encryption key?

The real use case is:

- Got a security key (32-char), need to hard-coded it into C++ code. But I don't want to have it plain text in C++.
- So I choose a password (like 8-char long), pass this to a hash function, like SHA2 and get a 128 bytes hash.
- Encrypt the 128 bytes hash with my security key, and save that output **encrypted string** to C++ code.

When use using the application:

- Prompt for password (8-char).
- My application take the password and generate the hash through SHA2
- Decrypt the **encrypted string** with the SHA2 hash to get the original security key (32-char).

Since the design has to put the security code in C++, we wanted to find out a way to secure it. With the above mechanism, we are putting the original code in C++ directly.

Comment: You shouldn't be hard-coding something like this in the code. However, there are libraries that do encryption/decryption such as libcrypto.

Comment: Which function in libcrypto can do the encryption/decryption I mentioned?

Comment: AES_cbc_encrypt() can be used as a symmetric cipher, but this whole set up is suspect, since it sounds like you have just your client-side C++ application that is validating a key, which is really no way to do this. A much better way is to have your C++ program running on a server with a database that maintains the keys, which ensures that the client application has no access to them.

Comment: If you really have to store the data on the client side then at least derive the key properly from the password using something like PBKDF2 with a few hundred thousand iterations (it should run 0.1 seconds or longer).

Comment: That is current design (with DB). We need the offline version as in some use cases there's no internet access or no DB access. And the offline solution is necessary.

Comment: @Perseids, do you mean to use PBKDF2 to derive the key, rather than a hash function like SHA2?

Comment: Yes. PBKDF2 internally uses a hash like SHA256 though.

Comment: Another question - in my use case, a symmetric cipher, I can't use a ramdon IV for AEC_cbc_encrypt(). So either it has to be using a fixed IV or not using IV. Should I still use AEC_cbc_encrypt() or there's something fit for this?